# How do you multiply a variable by another variable

Tags: python

I am making a system where you can enter as many numbers as you want, then you can press 'f' to stop. Before you enter numbers, you can select a type. Only the addition type works. The multiplication and division doesn't.

```
   #Selecting a type
    type = input('What type? (+,*, or /)')

    while number != 'f':
        number = input('Enter a number. Press f to stop entering numbers.')
        if number != 'f':
            #I think it is going wrong here.
            if type == '+':
                current_number += float(number)
            elif type == '*':
                current_number *= float(number)
            elif type == '/':
                current_number /= float(number)

    print('Your answer is ' + str(current_number) + '.')
```

I expect the answer to be the correct answer, but every time, it just gives me 0.0.

Comment: Are  you sure you provided the whole code?

Comment: What is `current_number`? If it's zero, what happens when you multiply 0 * any number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current_number` does not seem to be defined in the snippet you provided.
Assuming you start with `current_number = 0` it is no surprise that you end up with 0 as a result for division and multiplication:

1. 0 * anything = 0
2. 0 / anything = 0

Comment: Ohhh I see. Thank you!

Comment: As a token of appreciation, could you please accept the answer (the tick mark beside the answer).

Answer (score 1):

So, your code doesn't work because `number` and `current_number` are never initialized, but I'm going to assume that you gave them initial values of `""` and `0.0` respectively (considering how addition works for you)

`0.0 * n == 0.0` for any float n in python, so you would need to initialize it as `1.0` in multiplication mode.